# Why are my fingers suddenly sluggish?

Tags: fingering, violin

I had a late night last night. I had played my violin several times during the day, and had no problems. Today, I woke up late (as is to be expected after getting to bed at 12:30) and had a slow start. When I tried playing my violin this afternoon, I felt a *little* sluggish, like you do when your a little sick or tired. I thought nothing of it, but now, I feel like my fingers are slowing down.

I haven't played since then, but when I try tapping my fingers around on the table or whatnot, my fingers are unable to keep a steady beat. Typing on a slab of glass also known as a smartphone is a chore; my fingers seem to have lost all of their speed and agility. I type at like 15 words per minute all of the sudden. It's like the myelin sheaths in my fingers spontaneously disappeared!

There is no pain involved at all, although when I try to tap on the table quickly my wrist can feel a bit... swollen? You know that feeling that you get when you move your fingers too fast, except my fingers shouldn't be moving too fast. They're going comparatively slower.

Do you think it's related to the late night or the violin playing or anything? Should I try to avoid the violin until this blows over, or will moving my fingers help this to go away?

Comment: Happens to me if I play my guitar for extended period of time and over tax the muscles.  When I used to run in races (5k, 10k, half marathon) the next day I could barely walk.  But with adequate rest, I always recover.  You will probably be fine in a day or two.

Comment: Interestingly, I had a small amount of exercise since writing this question, and although I haven't played all day since said moment, my fingers are much more responsive. It may have been a lack of blood movement. Maybe I just needed to get my blood moving. I'll update tomorrow if I remember...

Comment: So, I play online Video Games for a living and this also happened to me when I play overnight, but it’s not pain inducing at all, so I just let it go until it’s back to normal

Answer (score 1):

When something of this sort happens to me I use a metronome and start slow (4/4 at 100 bpm) and slowly build up. I'd suggest playing the instrument like a workout on alternate days and you should be able to build back the strength. Also I would recommend playing in-front of a mirror as this could also be caused by wrong posture, which can be easily corrected by seeing oneself in the mirror. Also make sure you are having a good nutrition as this influences how your body functions to demanding tasks.

Hope this helps !

SKRelan